# Bootstrap Modal doesn't open with javascript method

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I would like to open a bootstrap modal window with javascript. But this code doesn't work:

```
<a href="" id="openUser">Open Modal JS (failed)</a>

$(function(){
 $( "#openUser" ).click(function() {
   alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
 });
})
```

The alert message box is showing, it seems the modal does open but it disappear immediately!

if i open the modal with the document.ready function it works!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Any idea what could be wrong?
I can't open the model using the static method (that works as well)

```
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="whatEver">Open Modal Static Link (works)</a>
```

Because I have to do a jquery.load to put some external data into the modal with functionality (php Script).or ist there a way to do this with the static method?

The modal:

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you add the `bootstrap.js` file? and also show us your modal HTML.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap.js is included (Version 3.1.1). As i wrote it works well,when i open the modal with the document.ready(function

Answer (score 0):

This is usually related to the **z-index** of the modal, and the z-index is related to other things... The short hack is to have the modal contents as a child of the body element.

For the long answer you need to inspect all the page, the z-index property depends on **positioning** (must be relative, absolute, fixed) and on the *stacking context*. That means that you need to take a look to all the elements wrapping the modal. Further information on [this smashing magazine link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it will solve your Problem but, you should use just these ' or these " quotation marks. This caused some errors for me in the past.
You should mix them only if you have HTML code in your Javascript. Like this:

```
var $newdiv1 = $( '<div id="object1"/>' );
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by my self. What a stupid mistake! 
I missed the # in the href tag:

wrong:

```
<a href="" id="openUser">Open Modal JS (failed)</a>
```

correct:

```
<a href="#" id="openUser">Open Modal JS (work)</a>
```